# Text Area "Required field" in Slim

Tags: forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

im using form helper in Rails, i need a text_area_tag "Required" but i dont find how to do.

```
= text_area_tag 'comment', nil, size: "25x1", required:
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try this `= text_area_tag 'comment', nil, size: "25x1", required: true`

Comment: Works, = text_area_tag 'comment', nil, size: "25x1", required:true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `required: true` option.

```
= text_area_tag 'comment', nil, size: "25x1", required: true
```